# if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ } NOT WORKING on submit button

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin, isset

I have a problem where when ever I load my page it says that the form is done even when I don't press submit here is the code -

```
<?php
    $db_host = 'localhost';
    $db_name = 'info';enter code here
    $db_user = 'root';
    $db_password = '';

    try {
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $db_host . ';dbname=' . $db_name, $db_user, $db_password);
        echo "connected<br><br>";
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
        die();
    }

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $info = $_POST['info'];
        $date = $_POST['date'];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO info (name, phone, email, info, date)";
        $sql .= " VALUES (:name, :phone, :email, :info, :date)";
        $query = $db->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute(array(
            ':name' => $name,
            ':phone' => $phone,
            ':email' => $email,
            ':info' => $info,
            ':date' => $date
        ));

        echo "done<br>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Please post your HTML form also

Comment: what errors are you getting ?

Comment: is your form's submit button name `submit`?? please re-verify

Comment: add attribute name="submit" to your submit button

Answer (score 0):

Add a check so it checks or something is posted:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
  //You code
}
```

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Just use one `&&` condition along with your `isset`

Lets just say, if this is your submit button

```
<input type="submit" value="SomeValue" name="SomeName">
```

Then you simply use this as your if condition to check if your button with name "SomeName" has actually been pressed.

```
if(isset($_POST['SomeName']) && $_POST['SomeName']=='SomeValue')
{
   //Rest of your code
}
```

This If implies, your submit button has been pressed it after checking its value. Hope it helps.